# textarea not editable on touch

Tags: jquery, touch, textarea, tablet

so ive tried to use the code from the example on this page:

http://www.prodevtips.com/2008/11/12/jquery-ui-draggable-and-resizable-combination/

to make kinda the same boxes with textareas - resizable - draggable - with the icons in the cornes.

and it works great on pc. but on tablets i cannot seem to focus the textarea - i can still move it around and resize it (though resizing it works like crap) - im using jquery.ui.touch-punch.

i cant even seem to focus it programmatically :(

heres my code regarding this:

```
  function newCommon(tpl_id, sub_tag) {
    $("div[id*='el_div_']").css("position", "absolute"); // 1

    var newDraggable = $("#" + tpl_id).clone().css("zIndex", elCount + 100).attr("id", "el_div_" + elCount)
                                .addClass("resizable ui-resizable").prependTo("#workarea"); // 2

    newDraggable.find(".delete").click(function () {
        $(this).parent().remove(); // 3
    });

    var dragger = newDraggable.find(".dragger"); // 4
    dragger.bind('touchstart mousedown', function () { newDraggable.draggable({ containment: "#workarea" }); });
    dragger.bind('mouseend', function () { newDraggable.draggable("disable"); });
    elCount++;
    return newDraggable;
}


var types = {


    input: function (pos) {

        var draggable = newCommon("txt_div_tpl", "textarea");
        draggable.addClass("ui-dragdrop-droppableElement ui-dragdrop-toolboxElement ui-dragdrop-textElement useDefault");
        draggable.css({
            "top": pos.y,
            "left": pos.x
        });

        //draggable.click(function () {
        //    console.log("clicked!");
        //    console.log(input.ID.toString() + "ID");
        //    CKEDITOR.replace("como");
        //});

        draggable.resizable({
            handles: "all",
            minWidth: 160,
            minHeight: 160,
            ghost: true,
            stop: function () {
                $(this).stayInBox($("#workarea"));
                var margin = $(this).find(".dragger").width() * 2;
                $(this).find("textarea").width($(this).width() - margin).height($(this).height() - margin);
            }
        });

        return draggable;


    },
```

[image: and heres a pic of my element:]

any ideas what could be the problem?

Comment: update: i got the textarea focused by the following code:  `code` draggable.click(function () {
                console.log("clicked!");
                if ($(this).find("textarea").focus())
                    console.log("focused");
            });`code`
 - however i cannot move the cursor in the textfield - and all the editing options the ipad normally supply is not available - i can write in it - but only at the random location of the cursor

Answer (score 0):

Add event to disable the draggable when textarea is clicked and enable the draggable when textarea is blurred.

```
$(".draggable textarea").click(function(){
    $(this).closest(".draggable").draggable('disable');
}).blur(function(){
    $(this).closest(".draggable").draggable('enable');
});
```

Modify the opacity of the disabled state to 1 so that user do not know it is temporarily disabled.

```
.draggable.ui-state-disabled {
    opacity: 1;
}
```